# Invalid mint owner during set_collection Candy Machine v2

Tags: collections, upload, solana, candy-machine

i was trying to mint some nfts with candy machine but when i try to execute:

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts set_collection \
    -e devnet \
    -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json \
    -c example \
    -m C2eGm8iQPnKVWxakyo8QhwJUvYrZHKF52DPQuAejpTWG
```

I got this error:

```
throw new Error(`Invalid mint owner: ${JSON.stringify(info.owner)}`);
            ^
Error: Invalid mint owner: "11111111111111111111111111111111"
    at Token.getMintInfo (/Users/btk-macmini-01/Desktop/repo/peppermint/docs/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/client/token.js:731:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async parseCollectionMintPubkey (/Users/btk-macmini-01/Desktop/repo/peppermint/docs/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/various.ts:438:5)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/btk-macmini-01/Desktop/repo/peppermint/docs/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:941:34)
```

Someone knows why? I have tried putting a different address from the one with that i have created the candymachine and with I made the upload or also the same but the issue is the same, maybe there is something wrong with it or with other things?

This is an example of my json:

```
{
    "name": "#1",
    "description": "description",
    "external_url": "",
    "image": "0.png",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Background Color Woman",
            "value": "Light Blue"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Background color man",
            "value": "Metal Grey"
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "files": [
            {
                "uri": "0.png",
                "type": "image/png"
            }
        ],
        "creators": [
            {
                "address": "GM1ByqbTfgRwXEQCLJ2N4bsA3P1WcuyL9kZT79gLqYuE",
                "share": 100
            }
        ]
    },
    "compiler": "https://the-nft-generator.com",
    "symbol": "Test",
    "collection": {
        "name": "test",
        "family": "test"
    }
}
```

If i upload without execute set_collections it works but with a different name of the collection from the one specified in the jsons file

Comment: What is the pubkey of the wallet stored at `~/.config/solana/devnet.json` you can use `solana-keygen pubkey ~/.config/solana/devnet.json` to check the pubkey. I need this info to check if you have the same wallet as that nft

Comment: Is: GM1ByqbTfgRwXEQCLJ2N4bsA3P1WcuyL9kZT79gLqYuE, i have tried to change "C2eGm8iQPnKVWxakyo8QhwJUvYrZHKF52DPQuAejpTWG" with "GM1ByqbTfgRwXEQCLJ2N4bsA3P1WcuyL9kZT79gLqYuE" but nothing changes

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue here. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Not yet, the only solution i have found is to use collections.metaplex.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_collection` is used to set the collection field to all the nfts inside a Candy machine that has not started the mint (0 minted NFTs). To set a collection you can pass any NFT (that is a masterEditionV2) that has the same `updateAuthority` as the wallet that you used to create ur CandyMachine.

In this case you are trying to set a collection that uses [this NFT](https://solscan.io/token/C2eGm8iQPnKVWxakyo8QhwJUvYrZHKF52DPQuAejpTWG?cluster=devnet) (`-m C2eGm8iQPnKVWxakyo8QhwJUvYrZHKF52DPQuAejpTWG`), and you said that ur CM was created with the wallet that has pubkey `GM1ByqbTfgRwXEQCLJ2N4bsA3P1WcuyL9kZT79gLqYuE`. The NFT has updateAuthority `42NevAWA6A8m9prDvZRUYReQmhNC3NtSZQNFUppPJDRB` and thats a completly different pubkey that the one that you used to create the Candy Machine.

You can always use the [collection webpage](https://collections.metaplex.com). This webpage allows you to create and mint a collection NFT with certain metadata, and also will migrate (change the onchain collections to the new created collection) the NFTs that you pass on the website and this can be updated at anytime with more NFTs. This website WILL NOT migrate unminted nfts from a candy machine.

If you want to use [`set_collection`](https://collections.metaplex.com) make sure to provide, on the `-m` parameter, an NFT that has the same updateAuthority that ur Candy Machine. Also make sure that your Candy Machine has 0 minted NFTs.

Comment: Perfect this woks for me, last question: do you know how to change the name of the collection? I have the collection field in nfts metadata but phantom displays always: Collection nft. Thank you in advice

Comment: And also it remains an item that is reffered to the collection on my phantom interface, i don't know if it is right or not

Comment: If you are using the webpage to create and migrate the collection then you was able to upload and create a new collection NFT with metadata (name, image, description, etc). If you are using the default collection nft that is created with ur upload command you can give it metadata using Metaboss (https://metaboss.rs/update.html) or any NFT update webpage (https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/ for mainnet)

Comment: I have another question, specifying the name and the family of the collections in all the jsons of the nfts that are part of the collection, it is possible to see the name in the phantom wallet or i have to change with metaboss (can you provide a better explanation of how can i change the name with the update command? I can't find how to specify for example only the name to the specific default collection created even because it says to update nfts metadata but in my jsons there is already the collection field but it doesn't seems to work) or other update webpage?